# Jquery to append a div and to remove a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my problem,

I have a select box where i need to validate if the val() becomes 0, then append a text insed a span with class error stating that 'Please select a value'. Else need to remove that div. These happens when i click the submit button. Here is my code,

```
if ($('.combo option:selected[value==0]')) {
    var error_span = $("div.info-cont ul.map-list li span.right")
        .append("<br>Please select an appropriate value")
        .addClass('error');
} else {

}
```

Now the problem is, if a value is selected in the selectbox, my appended span should get removed. Any help. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want to explain this:

```
if ($('.combo option:selected[value==0]'))
```

To check if the selected item from dropdown has value 0, you can use the following:

```
if ($('.combo').val() == '0') // simpler and more readable :-)
```

Then, it will be simpler if you already put the error message somewhere in the document. All you need to do is show/hide it. For example:

```
<select id="dropdown-1" class="combo">
  <option value="0">-</option>
  <option value="1">Lorem</option>
  <option value="2">Ipsum</option>
</select>

<span id="error-dropdown-1" class="error" style="display: none">Please select a value!</span> <!-- hidden by default. can also use CSS instead of style="display: none" -->

<input type="button" id="demo-button" value="Demo" />
```

And the javascript (+ jquery):

```
$('#demo-button').click(function() {
  if ($('.combo').val() == '0') {
    $('#error-dropdown-1').show();
  } else {
    $('#error-dropdown-1').hide();
  }
});
```

Here is another example. Useful if you avoid IDs (perhaps you have dynamically generated dorpdowns):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#demo-button').click(function() {
        $('.combo').each(function() {
            var div = $(this).parents('div').get(0); // get the wrapper
            if ($(this).val() == '0') {
                $(div).find('.error').show(); // show <span class=".error"> inside the wrapper
            } else {
                $(div).find('.error').hide(); // hide <span class=".error"> inside the wrapper
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<div> <!-- wrapper for 1st combo + 1st error message -->
    <select class="combo">
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <option value="1">Lorem</option>
        <option value="2">Ipsum</option>
    </select>
    <span class="error" style="display: none">Please select a value!</span>
</div>

<div> <!-- wrapper for 2nd combo + 2nd error message -->
    <select class="combo">
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <option value="1">Dolor</option>
        <option value="2">Sit</option>
        <option value="3">Amet</option>
    </select>
    <span class="error" style="display: none">Please select a value!</span>
</div>

<div> <!-- wrapper for 3rd combo + 3rd error message -->
    <select class="combo">
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <option value="1">Consectetuer</option>
        <option value="2">Adipiscing</option>
        <option value="3">Elit</option>
    </select>
    <span class="error" style="display: none">Please select a value!</span>
</div>

<input type="button" id="demo-button" value="Demo" />
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But these select boxes are dynamically generated. So it might be 2 or more. We cannot use IDs anymore. I guess, an append and remove function will be the only chance of getting rid of it.

Comment: @Riyas I just edited the code. It can be used for dynamically generated dropdowns. It only uses class & tree/DOM traversing.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> if($('.combo option:selected[value==0]')){
> $("div.info-cont ul.map-list li span.right").append("<br>Please select an appropriate value").addClass('error');
> } else {
>
> $("div.info-cont ul.map-list li span.right").html("");
> $("div.info-cont ul.map-list li span.right").removeClass('error');
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jquery validator](http://goo.gl/Ret4), it does all this for you

Answer (score 0):

If your span (span.right) contains anything other then the error message (which I  think it does based on the use of the br-tag), this method will leave that content where it is.

```
var $select = $(".combo"),
    $span = $("div.info-cont ul.map-list li span.right");

if ($select.val() === 0) {
    $span.append(
        $("<span/>")
            .addClass("error")
            .html("Please select an appropriate value")
    );
} else {
    $span.children("error").remove();
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but something similar should do the trick.